# Batch: Echo all lines from a specific variable from a .txt file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a batch executable which finds and echo's a specific line: "Rating.RESP:" from a .txt-file eg. 'Rating.RESP: 50'. Numbers go from 0-100 and I want the console to prompt all variables and I do not want to copy it to another txt file.

Thus far I am trying to work with findstr:

```
for /F %%i in (data.txt) do (
echo %%i
findstr /m /c:"Rating.RSP: [0-100]"%%i  
)
```

Any tips? If this works I would be able to further extent the batch executable.

---

Based on @Gerhard 's help I made the following code:

```
set /p file=Drag data file in here.

echo.
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('type %file% ^| findstr /m "Rating.RESP: "') do echo %%i
```

The result is a list of 'Rating.RESP: ##'

Next up I'm trying to read the %%i and echo a warning when it exceeds 75 or below 25. Any idea's? I was thinking something with extracting the last two characters of the substring and check if it is within (or outside) the threshold. Don't need the help just yet, I'm trying to figure it out myself. Thanks again for the help with echoing Rating.RESP.

---

Sample input file:

```
*** Header End ***
    Level: 2
    *** LogFrame Start ***
    list: 1
    Procedure: proc
    leftanchor: Alert
    rightanchor: Suf
    XTime: 09:55:25
    list.Cycle: 1
    list.Sample: 1
    Running: list
    Scale1.RT: 2054
    Scale1.RESP: 1
    Response: t056
    Rating.RESP: 56
    *** LogFrame End ***
    Level: 2
    *** LogFrame Start ***
    list: 2
    Procedure: proc
    leftanchor: Kalm
    rightanchor: Opgewonden
    XTime: 09:55:28
    list.Cycle: 1
    list.Sample: 2
    Running: list
    Scale1.RT: 861
    Scale1.RESP: 1
    Response: t050
    Rating.RESP: 50
```

Comment: The expression `[0-100]` does not match numbers frmo `0` to `100` but characters from `0` to `1` (hence `0` and `1`), or `0` or `0`; to match what I think you are looking for you need this: `findstr /R /C:"Rating.RSP: [0-9]" /C:"Rating.RSP: [1-9][0-9]" /C:"Rating.RSP: 100"`. Anyway, please [edit] your question and provide input and output examples to clarify what you really want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original question is a little ambiguous: from comments, I think "*which finds and echo's a specific line: "Rating.RESP:"*" would be better as "*which finds and echo's a all lines containing the specific string: "Rating.RESP:"*". With that assumption, and your additional comments about detecting out-of-range values, I think the following will do the trick:

**alert.bat**

```
@echo off
    setlocal
    set LOW_LIMIT=25
    set HIGH_LIMIT=75

    set /p file=Drag data file in here.

    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%a in ( `findstr "Rating.RESP: " "%file%"` ) do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "WARN="
        if %%b LSS  %LOW_LIMIT% set "WARN=  ** Value too low **"
        if %%b GTR %HIGH_LIMIT% set "WARN=  ** Value too high **"
        echo %%a%%b!WARN!
    )
```

Presented with a file containing:

```
something else
something else
Rating.RESP: 10
something else
something else
Rating.RESP: 50
something else
something else
Rating.RESP: 80
something else
something else
```

this will produce the output:

```
C:>alert.bat
Drag data file in here.data.txt
Rating.RESP:10  ** Value too low **
Rating.RESP:50
Rating.RESP:80  ** Value too high **
```

Notes / Assumptions:

- There is no need to `type` the file and pipe it into `findstr`: we can just give the file on the command-line.
- Using `usebackq` option allows use of double-quotes (both in the string to be found and, if necessary, the filename). This isn't strictly necessary, but often prevents problems.
- [**Update**] I have removed the `/b` from the original version of this answer as `Rating.RESP` doesn't always (ever?) start at the beginning of the line.
- Using `tokens=1,2` with the default delimiter (space or tab) will break matching lines into `Rating.RESP` (in `%%a`) and the numeric value (in `%%b`).
- The current code **assumes** that lines with `Rating.RESP:` will *only* be followed by valid numbers, **and** that there are no leading zeroes (e.g. `07`). If either of these assumptions is false, some extra code will be needed. (The problem with leading zeroes is that `CMD` treats them as octal, so `09` would be considered an invalid number).
- Use of `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` allows us to both `set` the value of `WARN` *and use it* within the body of the `for` command.

**Enhanced Checking**

If there *is* a need to detect invalid numbers, or to handle numbers with leading zeros, then the following will do the job:

```
@echo off
    setlocal
    set LOW_LIMIT=25
    set HIGH_LIMIT=75

    set /p file=Drag data file in here.

    for /f "usebackq tokens=1,2" %%a in ( `findstr "Rating.RESP: " "%file%"` ) do (
        setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
        set "WARN="
        for /f "delims=0123456789 tokens=1" %%x in ("%%b") do if not "%%x" == "" set "WARN=  ** Invalid number **"
        if not defined WARN (
            set "NUM=000%%b"
            set "NUM=1!NUM:~-3,3!"
            set /a NUM=!NUM!-1000
            if !NUM! LSS  %LOW_LIMIT% set "WARN=  ** Value too low **"
            if !NUM! GTR %HIGH_LIMIT% set "WARN=  ** Value too high **"
        )
        echo %%a%%b!WARN!
    )
~
```

**Notes**

- The `for /f "delims=0123456789 tokens=1"` line detects non-digits in `%%b`. By using all digits as separators, a purely numeric string will set `%%x` to an empty string (since there is nothing *but* separators). However, if there are any non-digits, then the first run of them will be extracted, and `%%x` will no longer be empty. The rest of the main loop is only executed if this didn't generate a warning.
- When working with numbers (e.g. `SET /A`, or `IF ... GTR ...` etc.), batch-files treat leading zeros as octal: `010` would be treated as `8`. To allow leading zeros in decimal numbers, we:

  - First create `NUM` with "sufficient" leading zeros. `08` would become `00008`; `100` would become `000100` etc.
  - The expression `!NUM:~-3,3!` takes the last three characters of `NUM`. Because of the preceding step, this will always be zero-padded (`00008` -> `008`; `000100` -> `100`). The value of `NUM` is replaced by `1` followed by these three characters (e.g. `1008` or `1100`).
  - Now that there are no leading zeroes, we use `SET /A` to reduce the value by 1000 (e.g. `8` or `100`). This can now be used safely in the limit tests.

With an input file of:

```
    Rating.RESP: 15
    Rating.RESP: 85
    Rating.RESP: 09
    Rating.RESP: 026
    Rating.RESP: 26
    Rating.RESP: xx
    Rating.RESP: 9x
    Rating.RESP: x9
```

we now get:

```
Rating.RESP:15  ** Value too low **
Rating.RESP:85  ** Value too high **
Rating.RESP:09  ** Value too low **
Rating.RESP:026
Rating.RESP:26
Rating.RESP:xx  ** Invalid number **
Rating.RESP:9x  ** Invalid number **
Rating.RESP:x9  ** Invalid number **
```

(With the original version, `026` would have been treated as octal, becoming `22` decimal, and would have triggered the "too low" warning).

Comment: I really like the suggestion and I think I'm getting on the right track. However, it seems like the console does not recognize the values. For every Rating.RESP it echo's the %LOW_LIMIT% warning. For example: ( Rating.RESP: 73%b ** value too low -25- **)

Comment: If by "_the console does not recognize the values_" you mean you're trying to run some of the above commands directly from a command-prompt (as opposed to inside a `.BAT` file), then that won't work.. a `FOR` command at the prompt should only use single percent signs (`for %a in ( ... ) do .... %a ...`). Also, `setlocal` will only work within a batch file (so enabling delayed expansion won't work).

Comment: No im running from .bat file

Comment: I've just copy-pasted what I posted back to my machine (in case something went wrong when I wrote the answer) and it works ok... can you try with an _exact_ copy of the script I posted: if that fails, can you post an _exact_ copy of an input line that causes problems, using back-ticks (\`....\`) at either end, e.g. `Rating.RESP:  73`. If that works, but you've modified your bat-file, post your version of the line where you test for a low-limit in the same way.

Comment: @Derek I've updated the answer by removing the `/b` (and added a version with extra checks... just in case needed). I've also edited the question to include the sample input you added to your (now-deleted) answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do that, if I wasn't looking to only return instances followed by numbers `0` through `100`.

```bat
@Find "Rating.RSP:"<"data.txt"
```

It could also be made case insensitive if required:

```bat
@Find /I "Rating.RSP:"<"data.txt"
```

**[Edit /]**
Update due to modified/extended question

```bat
@Set /A Lo=25,Hi=75
@Set "_="&Set /P "_=Drag file here >"
@If Defined _ For /F "Tokens=2Delims=:" %%A In ('Find "Rating.RESP: "^<"%_%"'
)Do @If %%A Lss %Lo% (Echo Value too low:%%A
)Else If %%A Gtr %Hi% Echo Value too high:%%A
@Pause
```

Comment: @Derek, when you get online again, please mark compo's question as the accepted answer, this is the only way you can ever do it, don't try any other methods, gods and spaghetti monsters forbid any other method, so please mark this one so he can get his points he so badly wants

Comment: Acutally FindStr did the job, because I am interested in the number behind 'Rating.RSP: '. Therfore I need the whole string. I do not want to know how many times Rating.RSP: occurs in the txt file. Compo's suggestion did not work for me. Or I'm missing some point here.